# MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail - Exchange Active Sync

Tags: ios, email, activesync

I'm writting an iOS application, and I allow users to send e-mail from my application.
To detect if they are able to send email, I use the method **[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]**.

It works well except if I have an Exchange Active Sync account register. In this case, the canSendMail method returns false !

Anybody know why it seems that MFMailComposeViewController does not recognize my Exchange account as an email account? And what I could do?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with my MobileIron configuration. The certificate I received from the MDM does not allow me to send email from another application than Mail.

So: All works fine with Exchange and MFMailComposeViewController.

Comment: Hi ! I'm facing on the same problem. How did you do finally ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the ability to test with a phone that has an Exchange Active Sync account right now? If not try to get one.

Then see what happens if you just ignore that flag and try to send mail anyway. If in the end you can send email, then at least for the time being you could pop an ActionSheet that says "If you are using 'Exchange Active Sync', tap Continue, otherwise you should Cancel and configure a Mail account". This would at least let you continue working til Apple fixes it.

In any case you should enter a bug on this with Apple (bugreporter.apple.com).

Comment: Hello David, yes I have the ability to test with an Exchange Active Sync account. If I ignore the flags, the application raise an exception. So it seems there is a problem with Active Sync account... I will enter it on the bugreporter.apple.com